# How to perform penetration testing of Set Top Box

Tags: penetration-testing

I am newbie and have been doing penetration testing of Web and mobile application. Now I got a new task to perform penetration testing of Set Top Box(STB).

I am able to capture STB data traffic in Wireshark but apart from wireshark, is there any other tool or method available to perform penetration testing of STB?

As I can't put proxy in STB, I can't use tools like burpsuite, Fiddler, etc. Please let me know is there any workaround for this?

Any help would br appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that set-top box traffic is not encrypted, your proxies should still work fine assuming that they align with whatever protocol your STB normally uses. If it does not, I would suggest working with Scapy to manipulate traffic and use some sort of TCP/UDP fuzzer on the STB. It really depends on the model, and how it was designed for you to have the best chance of success with certain tools.